# How to Register and Use DLL files in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-1.1

I have moved a couple of DLL files in the BIN folder but Visual Studio is not picking these up. Do I need to manually register them for 1.1?

I know in later frameworks, it is as easy as moving DLL files in the BIN folder but the same is not working for framework 1.1. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Added reference to them in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the DLL in the project.

More info below;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I have done that but it is giving me an error message saying "Only assemblies with extension DLL and COM can be registered". Even though the two files I am registering are DLL files.

Comment: Then the reason might be that the assemblies have been created with a .NET version greater then 1.1. Is this the case?

Comment: I am attempting to register ASPOSE.CELLS.DLL for 1.1. I have been using this DLL for 4.0 and now attempting to use it for 1.1. This could very well be the reason.

Comment: You cannot use a DLL compiled with .NET Framework 2.0 or higher for .NET 1.1 applications. I think that ASPOSE.CELLS.DLL was compiled using .NET 2.0

Comment: ASPOSE.CELLS documentation says it does support 1.0 and 1.1

Comment: But do you have the right DLL for .NET 1.1? Because there are different versions of Aspose.Cells.dll

Answer (score 0):

Running the MSI file and Restarting Visual Studio 2003 resolved the problem. ASPOSE.CELLS.DLL is 1.1 compatible so backward compatibility was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare your assemblies to your web.config just like the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <compilation>
      <assemblies>
         <add assembly="MyDll"/>
      </assemblies>
   </compilation>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

You'll have also to make sure that your dll are compiled for .NET 1.1. Or else, it won't work.

Hope this helps you. Let us know if it is still not working.